# File upload with Javascript without user intervention

Tags: javascript, file, upload

I have a Firefox component for PDF signing that I invoke via Javascript. The problem is that this component outputs the signed PDF as a file on the user's filesystem - there is no way to get a byte[], stream or similar.

I need to post this signed PDF file back to the server. Is it possible to do this in plain Javascript, without additional Firefox components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this without user intervention, this would he a **huge** security hole.  Think about visiting a webpage and it being able to grab and upload any of your files without you doing a thing...you can see how this would be abused *really* fast.

You might be able to do this with a Firefox extension, I'm not sure of the security limitations it imposes (though I wouldn't be surprised if it disallowed this as well), but JavaScript would not be an option here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to access data on a user's file system within a browser unless you're doing it through an extension. This would be a huge security risk.

If the file can be put into an `<input type="file" />` element in Firefox, you can [use JavaScript to automatically upload the data](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/fileapi) to the server without user intervention, but you would need something to initially get the file into the page's memory, not the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Hell no - And for very good reason. You wouldn't want every Tom, Dick and Harry automatically grabbing all your files.

I believe it's the file input that needs user interaction. You *can* post the form automatically but you can't fill it in.

IMO your best bet is replacing the whole Firefox component with a single Java applet - I'd all but guarantee there's a Java project for PDF signing. Perhaps even Flash or Silverlight as long as you can do what you need with your PDF.