# Leaflet load shapefile by filename

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I refer to https://github.com/consbio/L.Control.Shapefile and test map.html,

it can upload shapefile and diplay shape file content.

**Goal: Don't  use upload button,and use fileName string or http url string to load shape file.**

I change the map.html code of the sample like this below:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([43.5,-116.9], 13);

// Basemaps
var topographic=L.esri.basemapLayer("Topographic").addTo(map);

// Shapefile control
var s = L.control.shapefile({ position: 'topleft' }).addTo(map);

//How to do?
var shapeZipFileName = 'shape.zip'; 
var shapeZipUrl = 'http://XXXXXXXX/shape.zip';  
???
s.fileToArrayBuffer(?);
```

I don't know how to feed the parameter to reach my goal.

Anybody can help me to implement it?

**Method 2.** use https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile

I try this sample,but I get the error below.

I also don't know how to fix it.

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: You mean you want to upload a file without user interaction? That's not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014587/file-upload-with-javascript-without-user-intervention

Comment: @nikoshr yes.I want to load local shape file by file name I assigned.Really? It's not possible to do this?

Comment: It is really not possible to do this in the context of an online page viewed through a standard browser. Read the post linked by nikoshr for explanations.

Comment: As I understand you need to read local file, then use it somwhere in your application. As I know it is impossible without small user interaction.