# How to append a specific file to FormData with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, form-data

I need to append a specific file to my FormData object using JavaScript.

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("input", '{ ... some json ... }');
form.append("files", "/C:/My/Path/File.txt");
```

I dont want to select the file through a input button.

All examples that i founded do this:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("input", '{ ... some json ... }');
form.append("files", input.Files[0], "/C:/My/Path/File.txt");
```

So i think that i have to load that file into a blob or file object. But i dont get it.

Hoy can i do it? Thanks!

Comment: i think that way.. 

var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

you can check docs here 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: _"I dont want to select the file through a input button."_: So you're asking the user to _trust_ you to not upload anything else from their computer. There has to be some user interaction for security purposes.

Comment: To be clear: you cannot do this. A website could grab arbitrary files from the user's hard drive this way.

Comment: I understand the security issues. I need to automate an api call. If i cant do this, should i try another language?

Comment: The language doesn't matter. The _browser_ won't allow you to load a file from a local system without user authorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acoording to @Andy comment and to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3014623/8037813, effectively it is not possible to do this by security issues.

Dont lose your time trying to do it.

Thanks.